# Find the convergence of $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n+1)^\frac{1}{3} - n^\frac{1}{3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to find what the series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n+1)^\frac{1}{3} - n^\frac{1}{3}$ converges to exactly or show that it diverges.

By taking the partial sum of the series $S_N$ = $ \sum_{n=1}^{N} (n+1)^\frac{1}{3} - n^\frac{1}{3}$ then $S_N = 2^\frac{1}{3} - 1 + 3^\frac{1}{3} - 2^\frac{1}{3} +4^\frac{1}{3}-3^\frac{1}{3} + ... + (N+1)^\frac{1}{3} - N^\frac{1}{3}$

And at the end I'm left with $S_N = -1 + (N+1)^\frac{1}{3}$ and $\lim_{N \to \infty} S_N = -1 + \infty= \infty $

So  $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n+1)^\frac{1}{3} - n^\frac{1}{3} = \infty$

Is this correct is my first question and my second question is does there exist any other method of finding what series to converge exactly?

Thank you in prior.

Comment: $-1-N^{1/3}$ is negative, yet each $(n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3}$ is positive.

Comment: Check again which terms cancel.

Comment: It is pretty obvious that such series is divergent, since it is a telescopic series with positive and unbounded partial sums.

Comment: you have not been careful enough. Write out $S_2$ and $S_3$ as separate calculations

Comment: Thank you guys very much for your comments. I edited it.

Comment: But the second question remains :p. Is there any other method to find what the series converges to exactly. I am also familiar with a method where I split fractions into A/smth + B/smth and find A and B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computation is right, up to this point:
$$S_N = 2^\frac{1}{3} - 1 + 3^\frac{1}{3} - 2^\frac{1}{3} +4^\frac{1}{3}-3^\frac{1}{3} + ... +N^{1/3}- (N-1)^{1/3}+ (N+1)^\frac{1}{3} - N^\frac{1}{3}$$

Note that once you cancel all terms you are left with
$$S_N=(N+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}-1$$

Comment: suggest  editing in penultimate term $+N^{1/3}- (N-1)^{1/3}$

Comment: @WillJagy good idea, ty

Answer (score 1):

we are allowed to write each summand as we wish, so I will try the sum of $-n^{1/3} + (n+1)^{1/3}$ to get, up to $n = N,$
$$ \small -1 + 2^{1/3} - 2^{1/3} + 3^{1/3} - 3^{1/3} + 4^{1/3}  \cdots -(N-2)^{1/3}+(N-1)^{1/3} - (N-1)^{1/3} + N^{1/3} - N^{1/3} +(N+1)^{1/3}  $$
Just a visual thing, the pairs that cancel are next to each other this way

Answer (score 1):

> **While summation of the telescoping series is trivial and immediately shows divergence of the series, the OP has asked if there are alternative approaches.   Herein, we give two straightforward ways forward.**

---

**METHODOLOGY $1$:**

Using $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ reveals

$$(n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3}=\frac{1}{(n+1)^{2/3}+n^{1/3}(n+1)^{1/3}+n^{2/3}}> \frac{1}{3(n+1)^{2/3}}>\frac{1}{3(n+1)}$$

Hence, we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \left((n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3} \right)>\frac13 \sum_{n=2}^{N+1}\frac1n$$

Inasmuch as the harmonic series diverges, the series of interest diverges also.

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$:**

Using $(n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3}=n^{1/3}\left(1+\frac1{3n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)-n^{1/3}=\frac1{3n^{2/3}}+O\left(\frac1{n^{5/3}}\right)$

Inasmuch as the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}$ diverges for $p\le 1$, the series of interest diverges also.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: You give a very good answer !(as usual !). $\to +1$. Cheers, Mark !

Comment: Thank you Claude!

Comment: My pleasure, Sir ! Glad to help !!!!

Comment: @Allorja Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  And Happy New Year! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Another idea:
$$
1=(n+1)-n = ((n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3})((n+1)^{2/3}+n^{1/3}(n+1)^{1/3}+n^{2/3}).
$$
Hence, roughly speaking, $(n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3}$ grows like $n^{-2/3}$. Hence, asymptotically, I'd expect $\sum_n (n+1)^{1/3}-n^{1/3} \sim \sum_n n^{-2/3}$, which is well-known to be diverging.